# Saving an image to DB. Displaying it on the next page to edit

Tags: mysql, php-7

I'm working on a website that allows for the uploading images. A template and a source image. I'm intending to store them as a BLOB in a database. Before the image is stored there however, it needs to be forwarded to the next page to allow editing.

My question is as follows; How do I forward and display the image on the next page? 
And once the edit is successful, how do I forward it to the database? There are 8 entries in the table. Only the first five of these need to be filled at this stage.

Note: I am new to PHP and MySQL.

```
CREATE TABLE Templates(
    templateId varchar(32) PRIMARY KEY,
    userId varchar(32),
    filetype TEXT,
    positions TEXT,
    reviewState TEXT DEFAULT 'p',
    timeAdded INT,
    timeReviewed INT,
    reviewedBy varchar(32),
    FOREIGN KEY (userId) REFERENCES Users(userId),
    FOREIGN KEY (reviewedBy) REFERENCES Users(userId)
);
```

This is the current HTML form I'm using to try and forward the image to the next page. Though it forwards to the next page, the image is not displayed.

```
<form action="/template/edit.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="name">Name</label>
        <input class="form-control" type="text" name="name" id="name">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="btn btn-default" for="image">Choose Image</label>
        <input class="inputfile" type="file" name="image" id="image">
    </div>        
         <input class="inputfile" type="file" name="overlay" id="overlay">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      </div>
      <button id="upload_img" class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Next">
  </form>
```

I considered uploading the image to a temporary directory, allow it for editing, THEN save it to the database and then delete the temp file.

I'm assuming there needs to be a separate php file to pull the image, like this? Assuming I can store and edit it whilst it's in the database.

```
<?php

  $id = $_GET['id'];
  $link = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "password");
  mysql_select_db("dbname");
  $sql = "SELECT filetype FROM dbname WHERE id=$id";
  $result = mysql_query("$sql");
  $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
  mysql_close($link);

  header("Content-type: image/jpeg");
  echo $row['dvdimage'];
?>
```

If there is any more information required, I'd be happy to provide it.

Comment: Every time you use [the `mysql_`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php)
 database extension in new code
 **[this happens](https://media.giphy.com/media/kg9t6wEQKV7u8/giphy.gif)**
 it is deprecated and has been for years and is gone for ever in PHP7.0+.
If you are just learning PHP, spend your energies learning the `PDO` or `mysqli` database extensions and prepared statements.
[Start here](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)

Comment: Wasn't aware that it has been gone. Thanks for your reply. I'll rewrite the PHP using the PHP 7.0 standarts.